# Thread.Sleep why not block the thread on example

Tags: c#, multithreading

`Thread.Sleep()` is putting main thread on hold for certain number of milliseconds. I would expect `Thread.Sleep()` to block main thread even if it's called from different thread (`Task.Run()` creates new thread in fact), why when it comes to `PleaseWait()` my loop which is on main thread is still executing since `Thread.Sleep` was called? It should be paused to me. Or is it because in fact that `Thread.Sleep()` called on different thread by Task.Run is now not exactly `Thread.Sleep` for main thread now but it is referring to the new thread created in `Task.Run`. Means it's not Sleep for main thread but for thread created on `Task.Run` side ? Hope it's clear.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Task.Run(() => PleaseWait());

            var n = 0;
            while (n < 10000)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(n);
                n++;
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }


        public static void PleaseWait()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
            Console.WriteLine("After sleep");
        }
    }
```

Comment: `I would expect Thread.Sleep() to block main thread even if it's called from different thread` the answer is no, you are wrong. it does block the thread where you say `Thread.Sleep()`

Comment: `Thread.Sleep()` blocks the current thread it is called from, why would you think if you are running on a subsequent thread (using task run) it will block any other thread

Comment: It is clear what you expected, it is not clear to me why you expected it. You have two threads, the main thread, which then spawns an additional thread. On this additional thread you call `Thread.Sleep`, can you explain why you expected the main thread to be blocked by this? Perhaps there are other issues we need to address here as well.

Comment: [Thread.Sleep Method - Suspends the ***current thread*** for the specified amount of time](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.sleep)

Comment: @TheGeneral I think Thread.Sleep(x) is like Task.Delay(x).Wait()

Comment: Although it might do the same thing (**Block** your thread) written like this, they aren't the same thing.

Comment: @TheGeneral i think as i stated above they block thread (Thread.Sleep(x) or Task.Delay(x).Wait()) however the additional thing for task.Delay is we can await it :)

Answer (score 6):

> I would expect Thread.Sleep() to block main thread even if it's called
>   from different thread

Lets visit the documentation

[Thread.Sleep Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.sleep?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Suspends the current thread for the specified amount of time.

Meaning it blocks the thread it is called from, Case closed